# I've made a sentence but I'm not sure where I need to place 'enough' here

Tags: sentence-construction

I've made a sentence but I'm not sure where I need to place 'enough' here.

> 1. I need to get ***high enough a score*** that I can pass this exam.
> 2. I need to get ***a high score enough*** that I can pass this exam.
> 3. I need to get ***high enough scores*** that I can pass this exam.

Comment: This is one of those that even natives fall over… Essentially, you started out in the wrong direction & are trying to fix it halfway through the sentence, which is always going to sound awkward. 3 feels like the best recovery, but try moving the word 'score' earlier in the sentence & see where you get.

Comment: Were I you, I would just use `I need to get a score high enough that I can pass this exam.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your attempts is actually correct. What you want is:

> 4. I need to get a high enough score to pass this exam.

Possibly

> 5. I need to get a score high enough to pass this exam.

Personally number 5. seems best to me since it doesn't separate the quantity from the goal. The "high enough" relates to two things. On the one hand to the score (the thing that needs to be high enough) and the other hand the goal (how high is high enough? whatever lets me pass me this exam).  An even wordier version could also be

> 6. I need to get a score, which is high enough to allow me to pass this exam.